# Laplace transformation with mass

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, laplace-transform

I am doing some QFT calculations with the fermion mass term, and it is making the calculation much more challenging.

Say I have

$$F(t,m) = \int_0^1 dx \frac{1}{1-x}\frac{1}{(t ~(1-x)+m(1-x)^2)^\epsilon}\frac{1}{t}$$

where $\epsilon$ is the dimensional regularization parameter.

I would like to take a Laplace transformation
$$\mathcal{L}[F(t,m)]=\tilde{F}(s,m)$$
and this seems much more difficult than computing $\tilde{F}(s,0)$, which (at least using mathematica) one can trivially compute as

$$\tilde{F}(s,0) = \mathcal{L}\left[\frac{1}{t^{1+\epsilon}}\right]\int_0^1dx\frac{1}{(1-x)^{1+\epsilon}}\\
=s^\epsilon \Gamma[-\epsilon]\int_0^1dx\frac{1}{(1-x)^{1+\epsilon}}\,.$$

However, things are a lot more complicated now that the $\epsilon$ exponentiated denominator entangles $\tau$ and $x$ for the $m\neq 0$ calculation. Of course, one of the complication stems from $x$ being integrated, but even an unintegrated case such as

$$\mathcal{L}[G(t,m)]$$
where
$$G(t,m)=\frac{1}{t}\frac{1}{(t+m)^\epsilon}$$ seems quite nontrivial.

Any insight on how to proceed or advice on useful properties/tricks of Laplace transformation that may be helpful in this calculation?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'd probably get a better answer on mathematics stackexchange, not saying that people here couldn't address it, but your issue is purely mathematical in nature.

Comment: What is it you hope to use the Laplace transform for?

Comment: actually I would even appreciate knowing how to compute the integral even without the Laplace transform as well.

Comment: This is a comment that I'm not sure is relevant to this question. This integral appears to be divergent. If this integral was obtained from Feynman's parameter formula, then something seems wrong, because it shows a divergence that is unrelated to the physical divergence. Also, if you don't care about this divergence about $\frac{1}{1-x}$, you could probably rewrite this integral as an expansion of ε by using $(a+b)^\epsilon=\exp(\epsilon\log(a+b))=1+\epsilon \log(a+b)+O(\epsilon^2)$, but I'm not sure that would make sense, since the coefficients look like including unphysical divergence.